# reset app on user exit

Tags: iphone, objective-c

is there a way to restore an app to the original settings when a user exits?

I need the app the reset every time it's closed out.

thanks so much.

Comment: You don't get a lot of time to do things when the home button is pressed.

Why not restore original settings on startup instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this method 
[application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

EDIT: question was little confusing.. if you read all the thread. Application was running in background, answer is UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend is needs to add in the info plist.

Comment: like applicationWillTerminate: maybe? the documentation says that: This method lets your application know that it is about to be terminated and purged from memory entirely.
that sounds right.

Comment: You can use applicationWillTerminate it's a small time window you have to do all your work... at the same time.. application:didFinishLaunching also has limited time else your application will force to quit..

Comment: his program will neither reach applicationWillTerminate nor application:didFinishLaunching. It just moves to the background, and if it comes to the foreground it looks like when he did "exit" the app.

Comment: In that case you can use applicationDidEnterBackground, applicationWillEnterForeground.. But I don't see why it wont exit.. you can add UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend in info.plist to exit app..

Comment: This answer is so wrong. As a developer, you should never call this method directly.

Comment: @diwup.. I know this is not the answer. if you read all the thread you will get what was going on. and which method you talking abt?

Answer (score 4):

Add the UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend key to your app's info.plist.  This will cause your app to terminate when the user hits the button.  Then don't load anything saved from NSDefaults (etc.) when your app restarts.

Comment: This is the best answer and all these other answers are ridiculous.

Comment: I agree, best answer.  iPhone 4 defaults to multi-tasking so it will run where it last left off.  Don't let the development version of your app fool you though... sometimes it will continue where it left off despite adding the UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend key... especially in the Simulator.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to keep data after the application end just don't save it. Nothing is saved automatically for you.

Don't use NSUserDefaults, CoreData and don't store things on the filesystem.

Comment: I'm not CoreData or storing on the filesystem. I just want the the first tabcontroller view to be displayed and the animations to start over.

Comment: so I guess your app was in the background.

Comment: it should show the first tabcontroller ... add UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend inside the info.plist

Comment: thanks, I'll try that. at the moment it gets stuck at the point where the user leaves the app (normally I would want this, but not in this case).

Comment: that worked. I checked the "Application does not run in background" in the info.plist

thanks everyone for the help.